# Is it considered bad form to edit a closed question?

Tags: discussion, edits, closed-questions

If I see a closed question with very bad spelling (spelling is not the cause of closure), should I attempt to edit it?

Comment: Well, closure is much different.

Comment: If your edits aren't going to measurably improve the quality of the question, then don't waste your time.

Comment: Only if you think/hope it will get reopened, really.

Comment: I once edited a _deleted_ question by mistake. These things happen.

Comment: To answer the title, yes. To answer the body, no.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends.

If the question is otherwise clear, on-topic, and complete (including any code samples necessary), and the only thing needed was a few edits to get it back on track, then feel *encouraged* to edit the question to shape.

However, if the question is unclear, or off-topic, or incomplete, then edits alone wouldn't be enough to help it along.

If you strongly feel that the effort to edit it is worth the end result - the question getting reopened - then it's appropriate to edit it.  If you don't feel this way, then your efforts can be better spent elsewhere.

Comment: Adding to this, there is a large downside with editing closed questions: a question gets pushed to the re-open queue *only* on the first edit after being closed. A second edit from the OP which might makes the question on-topic *won't* trigger the question going to reopen queue. Too often do I see questions in the reopen queue where someone did nothing more than just add a code tag of fix a minor spelling issue. Not only a waste of time for the reviewers, but it also robs the OP from redeeming the question by adding extra information and/or clarifying the goals.

Comment: ^this is the real answer.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Seems like that should be changed. The OP should never be robbed of the opportunity to redeem the question.

Comment: @user3386109 There have been discussions about this in the past – I'm too lazy to find them now though :-)

Answer (score 5):

The general advice (commonly said around here) of "don't edit turds" would seem to apply here. Like @TravisJ said, you can edit a question if your edit would turn it into an acceptable question for the site. Editing a salvageable question partway should also be ok if you are leaving it in a state that is better than it was and such that someone else could take and finish making it acceptable.

The things that you shouldn't edit are the "turds". If you see a question that asks "hiiii - what is the best programing languag i want to be programer plz need tutorials classes helpp advise sory for bad english i not no much bye", no amount of editing is going to bring that question anywhere close to being on-topic, so put on the blue dress and Let It Go.

Comment: Do questions like your example get posted on there? Isn't there some sort of automatic check for bad spelling and such things?

Comment: @theo2003 Yes, they do. Usually they get closed and downvoted into oblivion (-10 and further) and are deleted soon after. I've participated in downvoting and closevoting many questions that are like that. There is a filter but it doesn't always work.

Comment: @theo2003 - Yeah, unfortunately those questions do get posted to the main site. It is very hard for automation to find these with enough accuracy to be used, so often the community needs to have 5 users vote to close, and 3 to vote to delete, if something that bad shows up. This is why there are automatic post bans for users who continue to post that type of content. There are also several bots in chat that will attempt to guess at those types of posts, but while effective still cannot catch everything.